# how to click particular item in directive using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I am trying to click on a particular item using id in a template of a directive below is my directive

```
app.directive('dropdownmenu', function($window) {
    return {

         restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/dropdownmenutemplate.html',
            link: function($scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                $scope.click=function(e)
            {
                 var id = e.target.id; 
                 console.log("id value is"+id);
                }

            }
    };
});
```

Below is my dropdownmenutemplate.html

```
<div class="ss-example">
        <div class="ss-btn-toolbar" style="margin: 0;">
            <div class="ss-btn-group">
                <button class="ss-btn ss-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="ss-caret"></span></button>
                <ul  class="ss-dropdown-menu">
                 <li id="Action" ng-model = "action1" ng-click="click()"><a href="#" >Action</a></li>
                <li id ="Another" ng-click="click()"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li id ="Something" ng-click="click()"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>

                    <li class="ss-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /ss-btn-group -->

        </div><!-- /ss-btn-toolbar -->
    </div>
```

when I click "action" it should go to some function in the link and "action" should be printed I have tried both element.bind and watch functions element.bind is working for all elements I need it for specific item and watch is not working",
please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: create your jsfiddle for people easy to help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling ng-click="click()"

try

```
pp.directive('dropdownmenu', function($window) {
    return {

         restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/dropdownmenutemplate.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

               scope.click = function(){
                             alert("inside click function");
                 };
                scope.$watch('action',function(newVal){
                    alert("value changed");
                });


            }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks its working for particular item but I want to do this by using id value. for example i want to give like this <li id = "action" ng-click="click()"><a href="#">Action</a></li> so how can I get the id value inside click function of directive

Comment: scope.click = function(e){
  var id = e.target.id;
  console.log(id);
}

Comment: what is target here, I am getting Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: scope.click = function(**e**){ var id = **e.target.id**; console.log(id); }
Pass **e** parameter to click function
Here <li> will be the target

Comment: tried the same but getting same error, need to define anything in html? if I have multiple id's how it will differentiate particular id.

Comment: Pass event object from ng-click="click($event)" reffer this http://jsfiddle.net/U825v